# React Native reanimated doesn't work with interpolate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I try to use Animated.interpolate but I get a strange error that I've never had. How can it be solved ? Thanks

[image: -]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The variable that is using interpolate should be inside **useAnimatedStyle**.

```
const positionX = useSharedValue(-40);
const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const opacity = interpolate(positionX.value, [-40, 0], [0, 1]); // <- It must be here to work.
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: positionX.value }],
      opacity,
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this without naming `inputRange` or `outputRange`:

```js
import { useSharedValue, interpolate } from 'react-native-reanimated' // version 2.x

const animatedValue = useSharedValue(0)

const interpolatedValue = interpolate(
  animatedValue.value,
  [valueMin, valueMax],
  [interpolatedValueMin, interpolatedValueMax]
)
```

Note: In favour for better UX use `react-native-reanimated`, which uses the UI thread to perform animations instead of the JS thread

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to version 2.X from version 1,
then this needs to be renamed from `interpolate` to `interpolateNode`

more info here https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/migration/#1-interpolate-renamed-to-interpolatenode

Answer (score 0):

```
import Animated,{interpolate} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const scale = interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });

const borderRadius = interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 10],
  });
```

when i did it like this, my problem was solved

Answer (score -1):

Please check this documentation.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/event

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/code

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/interpolate

And try this.

```
Animated.useCode(
  () =>
    [
      //...
      Animated.interploate(...),
    ],
  [animated, offset]
);
```

Comment: I already checked it , I've worked before with Animated API, I just don't get what's the issue now..

Comment: Is react-native-reanimated 1 outdated and should stick to 2nd version maybe ?

Comment: Yes, Worklets are far better than declarative api.

Comment: Thanks for the advice . I still hope someone can help me out with this one, it really bothers me

Comment: Added some example I would like you to try.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find the issue.The version of react-native-reanimated was 2.2.0 and I installed the 1.12.0 one and is finally working